# TypeScript Disallow Unecessary optional chain expression

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

Is there an es lint rule or typescript config to disallow the following ?

```
let s: string;
s = 'a';
s?.toLocaleLowerCase();
```

In my opinion, s is not nullable so no need to do optional chain assertion, it just confuses other developers

Answer (score 5):

The [`typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unnecessary-condition.md) rule does this.